how to use environment variables for file links in html
Our business uses Macro Express Pro to create macros to assist with daily tasks. Rather than prompting the user once for their user multiple times for pieces of data, I'm creating an HTA and using VBS (chosen scripting language for my business) to process the entry.
My issue is I'm trying to use environment variables rather than hard coding the path to things like an image. For example, instead of using this to get the image:
<img src="C:\Users\MS-ID\Documents\Macro Express\MyImage.png">

we do something like this:
<img src="%USERPROFILE%\Documents\Macro Express\MyImage.png">

or this:
Dim User
Dim objShell
User = objShell.ExpandEnvironmentStrings("%USERPROFILE%")

<img src=" & User & "\Documents\Macro Express\MyImage.png">

I've checked the path and it's correct. All I get is the box with an X for broken image. The image is fine.

It IS similar, but I'm looking specifically on how to use the environment variable within the <img src> tag. Everything I've tried doesn't work.

My apologies. I reviewed my question and I was using %USERNAME% for C:\Users\MS-ID instead of %USERPROFILE%. Thank you for your time.

Do you mean that it works with that change, or just that you needed to update the question, but you are stilling having the same problem?

@NotTheDr01ds It works with that change. Thank you.
